# OSPF md5 encryption from Quagga to BIRD

Tags: debian, quagga, bird

I am migrating from Quagga to BIRD; however after setting things up, the other OSPF "routers" do not see me.

I think I have not setup properly the MD5 directive.

My similar setup in Quagga is:

```
ip ospf authentication message-digest
ip ospf message-digest-key 5 md5 SecreTPassword
```

In BIRD I have done:

```
area 0.0.0.0 {

    ...

    interface "eth0" {
        cost 1000;
        password "SecreTPassword";
        authentication cryptographic;
    };

    ...
};
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because the MD5 digest authentication key (5) was forgotten.

```
          area 0.0.0.0 {

            ...

            interface "eth0" {

                    cost 1000;
                    password "SecreTPassword" {
                        id 5;
                    };
                    authentication cryptographic;
            };

           ...
    };
```

After setting it up, and restarting BIRD, the other OSPF aware routers starting listing the BIRD router in the OSPF neighbors list.